# Trouble with converting the negation of a formula to CNF

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to convert the negation of the following formula to CNF:

**(p → (q → r)) → ((p → q) → (p → r))**

These are the steps I am following:

¬((p → (q → r)) → ((p → q) → (p → r)))

¬(¬(¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∨ (¬(¬p ∨ q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

¬(¬(¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∨ ((¬¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

¬((¬¬p ∧ ¬(¬q ∨ r)) ∨ ((¬¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

¬((¬¬p ∧ (¬¬q ∧ ¬r)) ∨ ((¬¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

¬((p ∧ (q ∧ ¬r)) ∨ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

(¬(p ∧ (q ∧ ¬r)) ∧ ¬((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

((¬p ∨ ¬(q ∧ ¬r)) ∧ ¬((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

((¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∧ ¬((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∨ r)))

((¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∧ (¬(p ∧ ¬q) ∧ ¬(¬p ∨ r)))

((¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∧ ((¬p ∨ q) ∧ ¬(¬p ∨ r)))

((¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∧ ((¬p ∨ q) ∧ (¬¬p ∧ ¬r)))

(¬p ∨ (¬q ∨ r)) ∧ ((¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ ¬r))

(¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ ¬r)

This is where I'm getting stuck - I am now left with 2 sets of disjunctions, and 1 conjunction. I know CNF is a conjunction of disjunctions, so clearly I must've done something wrong here.

The only thing I can think of to convert the conjunction to a disjunction is perhaps using the distributive law, but I can't figure out how to apply it in a case like this.

Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good so far.  Now just remove the rightmost pair of parentheses.
$$
\lnot [(p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies q) \implies (p \implies r))] \\
\lnot [\lnot (\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \lor (\lnot (\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \lor r))] \\
(\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \land \lnot (\lnot (\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)) \\
(\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \land ((\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot (\lnot p \lor r)) \\
(\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \land ((\lnot p \lor q) \land (p \land \lnot r)) \\
(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot p \lor q) \land p \land \lnot r 
$$
This is already in CNF.  But you can simplify it by noting that $p$ prevents $\lnot p$ and $\lnot r$ prevents $r$, yielding:
$$
\lnot q \land q \land p \land \lnot r,
$$
which is always false.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my workings! So the original question is that you must convert the negation of the original formula to clausal form, which is a version of CNF. According to the book I'm working through, a formula can only be in CNF if all clauses are disjunctions of literals, all connected by conjunctions. So as we have 1 clause that is a conjunction (p ∧ ¬r), this formula is technically not in CNF, therefore it is impossible to convert to clausal form. Do I have that right?

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you're saying - by removing the parentheses, it is in CNF. My bad!! Thanks a lot for the assist!